# Windows 10 how to create a command line program

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, jar

I've just downloaded swagger-codegen-cli (doesn't matter what it is, it's just an executable jar) in a Windows 10 OS, which runs from the command line. So to execute it I must go to the corresponding folder (in the command prompt, of course), and there run:

`jara -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar <command> [<args>]`

which is, as you may see, quite annoying. I know I can create a batch file (`.cmd` extension) and add the path to that file in the `PATH`environment variable but I'm not sure how to write that batch. Can anyone say how to write that batch so I can write something like `swagger-codegen <command> [<args>]` from anywhere in the command line?

It would be like an alias which I can add to `PATH`, do I make myself clear? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: where ever the executable is just put it in quotes "C:\temp\crap\myexecutable.exe" so I guess it would look something like this in your batch file. Also batch file would be .bat extension.  

jara -jar "C:\temp\swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar" <command> [<args>]

Comment: Hi, we're not a script writing service. Write your batch, and put it in a path that's in your PATH environment variable.  Where are you getting stuck exactly? And what have you tried so far to get un-stuck?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 that's the thing, I don't know how to write a batch file, so I ask for help. I assume it's a simple task and it isn't something I need to do every day, so it's not practical for me to dive into some batch documentation and/or tutorial. I was reading the Maven batch (it's at hand for me) and was quite complex, so I didn't know how to deal with the matter. BTY, I think the accepted answer is useful information for a newbie in this matter like me. Sorry if I made you lose your time, you don't have to pay attention to my questions if you think it's not worth it. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `jar` is at `C:\Program Files\Java\swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar`, then your `swagger-codegen.bat` should contain:

```
@echo off

java -jar "C:\Program Files\Java\swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar" %*
```

The `@echo off` is explained [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486061), and the `%*` represents the arguments passed to the batch file ([explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298769)).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create your bat file s-codegen.bat (for example).
Then add these lines...

```
@echo off    
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Java\swagger-codege\"
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar args
```

You may modify path according to the location where jar file is present.